# Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

Facing issue while running the android application on windows. It might be issue in "classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'".
But same application is running properly on mac.
How to fix this issue?

error image:

[image: Click here to see error image]

Comment: I'd take a guess the mac has a local cached copy and this machine does not. Bintray is dead https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/02/jfrog-jcenter-bintray-closure/

Comment: I deleted my answer because the OP doesn't seem to accept or even respond to answers to his questions (in general)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Save the "app"-folder of your protect
2. File -> Invalidate Caches -> Clear file system cache and local history -> Invalidate and Restart
3. Gradle (top-right) -> Window opens -> Click on the gradle icon in the top-left -> enter "gradle clean"